# How to create global variables in Erlang

Tags: erlang, global-variables, hook, ejabberd

I am writing an ejabberd module to filter packets. I need to get the hostname to pull some configs using `gen_mod:get_module_opt()`.

I have 4 important functions :

1. `start(Host, _Opt)` : This is an ejabberd function to load my module. I get the `Host` atom here
2. `filter_packet({From, To, XML})`: This is my packet filter hook. I cannot pass custom params to this function, as it is a hook in ejabberd.
3. `get_translation(XmlData)`: `filter_packet()` calls `get_translation()` in a loop
4. `fetch_translation(XmlData)`: called recursively from `get_translation()`. This is where I am calling `gen_mod:get_module_opt()`, and hence need the `Host`.

My question is, how can I take `Host` from `start()` and put it in a global variable, so that `fetch_translation` can access it?

Answer (score 9):

The "easiest way" is to create a named ets table, and put it in there.

```
start(Host, _Opt) ->
  ets:new(my_table, [named_table, protected, set, {keypos, 1}]),
  ets:insert(my_table, {host, Host}),
  ...

fetch_translation(XmlData) ->
  [{_, Host}] = ets:lookup(my_table, host),
  ...
```

Note that this is a "general" solution. Ejabberd might provide facilities for what you want, but I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Thx zed.

The module compiles ok but gives a 'badarg' error for 'ets:new(my_table, [named_table, protected, set, {keypos, 1}]),'

Comment: If table 'my_table' exists, you will get a badarg. You either need to check if the table already exists, or wrap it in a try-catch block

Comment: I'm not creating 'my_table' anywhere, except as given above.

Comment: I'm late but I wouldn't do this it creates unnecessary overhead. The easiest solution would be to use To#jid.lserver or if you need some more things you'll implement it as a gen_server.

Comment: this is a better solution than using a OTP process, which serialize every call and slower.

Answer (score 9):

It may sound as an overkill but you may consider implementing a very basic gen_server. It contains a state that is available to its callbacks and the data can be kept there. For your case you can write a module similar to this one:

```
-module(your_module_name).

-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-export([start/2, filter_loop/1]).

start(Host, Opt) ->
  %% start the named gen server
  gen_server:start({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Host, []).

filter_packet({From, To, XML}) ->
  %% do your thing
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {fetch_translation, XmlData}).

%% this will be called by gen_server:start - just pass the Host
init(Host) ->
  {ok, Host}.

handle_call({fetch_translation, XmlData}, _From, Host) ->
  %% do your thing
  {reply, ok, Host}.

%% you can ignore the rest - they are needed to be present
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
  {noreply, State}.
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
  {noreply, State}.
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
  {ok, State}.
```

Answer (score 2):

You define your global variable on your module top...like below

```
-define (Your Variable, "your host name here").
```

eg.

```
-define (RelayHost, "smtp.gmail.com").
```

and you can use this Global variable in all your method in your module.

```
io:fwrite("Global Value ~p", [?RelayHost]).
```

-AjAy

Comment: -define does not define variables. It defines compile-time constants.

Comment: It is not possible to define a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a new message filtering process and register it using `erlang:register/2`, then route all `filter_packet/1` requests through it (a potential bottleneck).

```
-define(?SERVER, msg_filter).

start(Host, Opt) ->
   {ok, Pid} = spawn(?MODULE, filter_loop, [Host, Opt]),
   register(?SERVER, Pid).

filter_loop(Host, Opt) ->
   receive
      {Pid, filter_packet, {_From, _To, XML}} ->
           Trans = get_translation(XML, Host),
           Pid ! {?SERVER, translation, Trans}, 
           filter_loop(Host, Opt)
   end.

filter_packet(Pack) ->
   ?SERVER ! {self(), filter_packet, Pack}
   receive 
      {?SERVER, translation, Trans} ->
           % wrap translation
           UpdatedPacket
   end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you are filtering incoming packets, then To#jid.lserver might be your host.

Comment: Hi andi5. Can you explain what "To#jid.lserver" means. How can i set / get it?

Comment: This is only best guess, but I suppose that To is a variable bound to a record of type jid (see the record definition in src/jlib.hrl, at the bottom). To#jid.lserver means that you want to access the lserver field of the record, where lserver is the lower-cased version of the jid's domain. If you have problems in the shell, run rd(jid, {user,[...]}).

Answer (score 1):

guessing for your description than you are in a single-domain ejabberd deployment (no virtual hosts),

yo can get the local XMPP domain using the ?MYNAME macro (see ejabberd.hrl for the definition).

Answer (score 1):

Try use [persistent_term](https://erlang.org/doc/man/persistent_term.html):

```erlang
1> persistent_term:put(hello, <<"world">>).
ok
2> persistent_term:get(hello).       
<<"world">>
3> persistent_term:erase(hello).
true
4> persistent_term:get(hello).  
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  persistent_term:get/1
        called as persistent_term:get(hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create global variable but you can define a record outside your functions and create an instance of that record with properties then pass it down to the methods you call. Therefore, you can only share one record via method parameter.